# How Do I Stop Visual Studio 2010 Editor From Making Code Hyperlinks?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Its quite annoying.

Example:

```
private const string someUrl = "http://foo.com";
```

I don't want the text to be turned into a hyperlink in the code editor.

Any ideas how to turn this off?

Comment: FYI, I just put up an [extension to make them stand out much less visually](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/9460c7e1-ea07-41f4-80ce-e1da4073859e), by keeping the URL highlight from changing the color (it just adds the underline).

Other than that, any suggestions on how to improve the feature that would make it useful instead of annoying?  Thanks!

Comment: Terrible feature. It hides all other important stuff, like highlighting code inside the sting. Example: `$"<a href="http://site?lang={lng}"`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Tools, Options, Text Editor, C# (or any other language), Enable single-click URL navigation.

Comment: You can go to All Languages and uncheck it for all different source files.

Comment: I would like to still be able to click links. I just don't want them to be blue, which hides the syntax highlighting

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about VS2010 but, in VS2008, you can open up `Tools`, `Options`, `Text Editor`, `<Your Language>`, `General`, there's a `Enable single-click URL navigation` checkbox that you should de-select.

With any luck, Microsoft won't have moved it too far from there in VS2010 :-)

Comment: Correct too. SLacks got in earlier (by 1 minute!), so i gave him the correct answer, but gave you a vote. =)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a somewhat dated question but when looking for a solution to programmatically update the date in a URL I was sending requests to, which VS2019 turning the string into a hyperlink was breaking, I just concatenated the `"https://"` with the rest of the URL and was able to use the `$@"string"` to achieve what I wanted to do. No need to toggle options or add extensions.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + 
$@"url.com/startDate={DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}");
```

Comment: String concatenation isn't universally available, but this is a nice solution for situations that allow it